# OAUTH Flow in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, rest-api, oauth

I need to create the Rest API in magento in 1.x or 2.x and I need to expose to the third party , I have doubt on the authentication how its going to be carried out for the OAUTH

->How the 3rd party get the consumer key ,Request token and Access token if all are other is Automatic process for the usage of the rest API using OAUTH.

->The process is getting the consumer key ,Request token and getting the Access Token.

If anybody done with same scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 uses 2-legged oAuth Handshake in order to retrieve oAuth tokens by the remote integration.

Here is [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html)

Comment: I think OAUTH 1.0 is implemented in magento2 and is implemented as the authorize or for 3rd party login/sigup . I think instead of complex , we use as token based authentication ,which is good.